# WSO2 Api Manager 3.2.0 How Expose a SOAP Service as a REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, mediator, api-manager

I Use this document but this is Don't work:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/tutorials/expose-a-soap-service-as-a-rest-api/

for example automatic create this mediator for input and it's not work :

```
 <header description="SOAPAction" name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" value="http://tempuri.org/ILivePublisher/Candles"/>
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
<property expression="json-eval($.Candles.instrumentIsin)" name="req.var.Candles.instrumentIsin"/>
<property expression="json-eval($.Candles.interval.Interval)" name="req.var.Candles.interval.Interval"/>
<property expression="json-eval($.Candles.since)" name="req.var.Candles.since"/>
<property expression="json-eval($.Candles.to)" name="req.var.Candles.to"/>


<payloadFactory description="transform" media-type="xml">
  <format>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <web:Candles xmlns:web="http://tempuri.org/">
  <web:instrumentIsin>$1</web:instrumentIsin>
  <web:interval>
    <web:Interval>$2</web:Interval>
  </web:interval>
  <web:since>$3</web:since>
  <web:to>$4</web:to>
</web:Candles>

  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
  </format>
  <args>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('req.var.Candles.instrumentIsin')"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('req.var.Candles.interval.Interval')"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('req.var.Candles.since')"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('req.var.Candles.to')"/>

  </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property description="messageProperty" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/soap+xml"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the error response you got and the error trace in wso2carbon.logs? It would help to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Further, please follow this doc to create REST APIs from WSDL - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/design-api/create-api/generate-rest-api-from-soap-backend/